# Does mysqldump -–single-transaction guarantee data integrity?

Tags: mysql, isolation-level

[MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction) says

> --single-transaction

> This option sets the transaction isolation mode to **REPEATABLE READ** and sends a START TRANSACTION SQL statement to the server before dumping data. It is useful only with transactional tables such as InnoDB, because then it dumps the consistent state of the database at the time when START TRANSACTION was issued without blocking any applications.

My doubt is that, it says the isolation is set as **REPEATABLE READ**, but this may not guarantee a consistent database state.

For example, if we have a table `Employee`, and a table `Hobby`, and a table `EmployeeHobby` which stores employee id and hobby id.

When we use `–single-transaction` (i.e., `REPEATABLE READ`) to dump the database. Let's denote the transaction as `A`.

In `A` we first dump table `Employee`, then some concurrent transaction `B` insert a new employee into `Employee`, and `B` adds related hobby into `Hobby` and `EmployeeHobby` (this does not violate `REPEATABLE_READ` since `A` never reads `Employee` afterwards), and then `A` dump table `EmployeeHobby` and `Hobby`.

Eventually, the dumped data by `A` is not consistent, since `EmployeeHobby` contains the id of a employee that does not exist in `Employee`.

The dumped data is broken, isn't it?

What the doc says

> it dumps the consistent state of the database at the time when START TRANSACTION was issued

seems not to be achievable by setting it to be a `REPEATABLE READ` transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REPEATABLE READ ensures that the transaction does not read any changes committed by other sessions after the transaction's snapshot is established.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-consistent-read.html

> If the transaction isolation level is REPEATABLE READ (the default level), all consistent reads within the same transaction read the snapshot established by the first such read in that transaction.

This includes any reads against other tables. So once mysqldump's snapshot is established, it immediately applies to all InnoDB tables on that MySQL instance, even tables that it hasn't read yet.